# Палиндром на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему этот код верный, а нижний нет? Для чего нужна temp?

```
n = int(input('type num: '))
rev = 0
temp=n

while(n>0):
    rev = (rev*10) + (n%10)
    n=n//10

if temp == rev:
    print('palindrom')
else:
    print('not')
```

2 код:

```
n = int(input('type num: '))
rev = 0

while(n>0):
    rev = (rev*10) + (n%10)
    n=n//10

if n == rev:
    print('palindrom')
else:
    print('not')
```

Comment: переменная temp сохраняет начальное значение n, так как переменная n меняет своё значение в процессе выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что во втором случае вы меняете `n` и сравниваете потом с `n`:

```
if n == rev:
    print('palindrom')
else:
    print('not')
```

но из-за `while(n>0):` у вас `n` всегда при последующей проверке равно 0

именно поэтому в первом случае `n` и сохраняется предварительно в `temp`, чтобы потом сравнивать с первоначальным значением `n`

Comment: спасибо большое. Теперь все понятно